# Точность расположения пользователя на Google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация, location

Добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой определения точного местоположения пользователя при использовании карт Google Maps. Не могу понять, каким образом можно определять расположения пользователя так же, как это происходит в Навигаторах (Яндекс навигатор или Гугл навигатор).

Стоит задача создания приложения с частичной навигацией (показывать, где едет пользователь). Желательно, что бы был аналог гугл Навигатора при движении (стрелочка, которая показывает, где едет пользователь).

Пробовал использовать сторонние библиотеки для определения местоположения и на данный момент остановился на [SmartLocation](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib). К сожалению ее максимум это точность до 5 метров (остается голубой круг с областью). После изучения API Google не смог найти, где и как необходимо производить настройку карты.

Надеюсь, что вы сможете подсказать, куда посмотреть или как можно это реализовать.

Заранее спасибо!